# How secure is my method?

Tags: php, webserver, mysql, ios

I want to select data from a `MySql database` on an iphone device. The method I seem is the easiest one is to connect to a `php` file with `GET` arguments and then return it as a string.

Now I'm just wondering what are the chances that someone will find the `IP-address` and the file and use it from a place other than the app.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why you need to protect this IP + GET request. If you are trying to protect a paid service - you might want to check out a subscription model where you do the payment inside the application + use authentication tied to this purchase.

Answer (score 3):

The chances are 100%. It's easy for anyone to look at your code and find the URL inside it, or to watch the network traffic and infer how your requests are performed.

When you should think about your app's security, assume that this information is public and go from there.

If you want to slow down the attacker's work (but keep in mind that you won't be able to prevent it!), you can look into obfuscation and think about encrypting your HTTP traffic (be sure to verify the certificate in your application!).

Comment: Like you say I am very concerned about someone finding it in the network traffic. Is it possible to encrypt the http requests and responds?

Comment: You can always connect to your PHP front-end through HTTPS, but keep in mind that this will *NOT* protect you from the application user. He can still reverse-engineer your application, or even forge his own HTTPS certificate to perform a man in the middle attack (unless you perform strict checks on the HTTPS certificate). As I said, you really should assume that this IP address and web service are public knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea has nothing to do with security. At best, it's obscurity.

A PHP script which is accessible for everybody is public by definition. You may try to hide it a bit so that the average visitor won't find it immediately. But neither IP addresses nor file names are secret data, so anybody with a bit of motiviation will find them out sooner or later. And once the URL is known, people are free to share it.

If you want to make sure that only you can access the script, you need *authentication*. There are many different variations ranging from a simple password to sophisticated certificate-based authentication.

In your case, you're obviously dealing with low-value data. [HTTP Basic authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) may be the right choice. And of course you can implement your own password check.

Comment: I agree, although in this particular case, the credentials will have to be embedded in the application, and therefore provide no real security.

Answer (score 0):

No, no, no, no, no and no.  This is completely, completely 100% insecure.  There is no fixing it.  It is broken.  Not only will the IP of the SQL server be trivially discoverable (and with no possible way to prevent it from being discovered relatively trivially since any information needed to connect is contained within the application itself), but it leaves you wide open to injections and manipulation along the way as well.

The proper way to handle something like this is to configure a public web service that will run atop the SQL server instance and field valid requests for the application.  The web service will take care of sterilizing and validating that input is a legitimate use case that could be from the application, generate the appropriate SQL or, preferably, stored procedure call and then return the data to the application.

With any server type system, you should NEVER trust the client.  There might be very rare exceptions if you have strict control over the client, but even then it should be avoided if at all possible.

Comment: It does not seem like the SQL server have to be exposed, as it has a PHP application as frontend. But you are right, it is not possible to hide these GET requests from anyone who are interested. If you want to protect your service as a paid service, the solution could be to have a subscription model based on authentication of the users. Have they paid, yes - let them in. You would also need to build some protection if someone would share the credentials.

Comment: @Dogeatcatworld - I may have been reading too much in to it, but it sounded like he was planning on just passing the queries as parameters and returning the raw data set.  If I misunderstood that, then my answer should be interpreted a little differently.